# How can I trigger a gitlab pipeline job for a specific branch but not if the commit contains only changes to certain files?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

For example, I want a deploy job triggered but not if the commit contains changes relating to a Makefile and/or docker-compose.yml. How can I specify those rules/conditions? Thank to anyone who is willing to help.

Answer (score 3):

Combine `if` rule to test the branch, and use `changes` condition to test if the file is in the changeset. Be sure to order them correctly to make sure the rule with `changes` is first.

```yaml
my_job:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "main"'
      changes:  
        - makefile
        - docker-compose.yml
      when: never  # dont run when these files are changed on this branch
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "main"'
      when: on_success  # otherwise run normally on this branch only
```

See [rules:changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges) for more information.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I've tested it but it only "partly works". The problem is, when I change files other than these two and push changes together with the changes to either on of these two, the pipeline won't trigger. How can I configure the pipeline to check if only changes to those were pushed before triggering?

Comment: @Erokos In which case, to get that behavior, you instead (or additionally above) use a `if:changes:` rule with `when: on_success` that matches _every other_ file in the repository except these. You can use glob patterns like `"*/**"` to match everything except files in the root; then list the patterns of files in your repo root.

Answer (score 2):

this can be achieved with the rules block and the fact that the rules are evaluated sequentially and stop as soon as one rule applies.

> Rules are evaluated when the pipeline is created, and evaluated in order until the first match. When a match is found, the job is either included or excluded from the pipeline, depending on the configuration.
> https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules

this means you could do something like the following as a first rule, to ensure that it is never executed.

```yaml
rules:
  - changes:
      - docker-compose.yml
    when: never
```

Disclaimer: i did not test this, but based on the documentation it should work like this. see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules for further details